# Error when connecting Angular app with REST-Django service

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, google-kubernetes-engine, django-cors-headers

I have an web application deployed on GKE. Front-end service is Angular 17 app running on Official NginX Docker container Load Balancer with Ingress. Backend is REST-Django service running on Gunicorn running on Official Python container. The problem is when I want to reach the service (GET method) from Angular I get error `Reason: CORS request did not succeed` in Firefox browser - Chromium says `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. The Django service has installed CORS:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'corsheaders',
...

MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

In local docker-compose environment everything works like it should.

From Angular's pod/container I am able to curl the Django service and it responds in desired way.

Comment: By default, (some) servers do not allow requests made from a different origin (IP address). If you want to allow your server to accept requests from different origins, you should configure the cors policy. Please, search for "How to configure cors in django server?".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this.
Add this line to your angular app's header.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"/>
```